# getting failed to parse JSON/YAML response using swagger when inheriting from custom base controller class

Tags: c#, swagger-ui, asp.net-core-2.0

I am getting the error failed to parse JSON/YAML response. This occurs only if my controller inherits from a BaseController class. If I Remove the BaseController it works fine.

```
[Route("v1/helloworld")]
    public class ValuesController : BaseController
    {
        private SystemManager _mgr { get; }
        public ValuesController(SystemManager mgr):base(mgr)
        {
            _mgr = mgr;
        }
        // GET: api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/values
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT api/values/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/values/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
```

**BaseController.cs**

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
    {
        public SystemManager SysMgr { get; }

        public LogWriter Logger
        {
            get { return SysMgr.Logger; }
        }

        public BaseController(SystemManager sysMgr)
        {
            SysMgr = sysMgr;
        }

        public async Task LogAsync(Exception ex)
        {
            await LogAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ex, Formatting.Indented));
        }

        public async Task LogAsync(string message)
        {
            var le = new LogEntry()
            {
                Message = message
            };
            await Logger.LogAsync(le);
        }

        public string GetUsername() => User.Claims.Where(a => a.Type == "Username").FirstOrDefault().Value;
        public string GetIPAddress() => HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpConnectionFeature>()?.RemoteIpAddress?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
    }
```

Comment: You are missing responses for your actions. Your actions should return a `IActionResult` derived response.

Comment: no difference same error

Answer (score 0):

Was fixed by setting all method to protected in base controller class.